# Customized named entities is throwing vlaue error in spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using spacy to enter some customized entities to run NER.
Here is what I tried,

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Span
from spacy.util import filter_spans
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
phrase_matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

#countries = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in ['Canada', 'United States', 'Mexico']]
#days = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
                                        #'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']]



food_list = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in [
    'breast milk',
    'Diet: Christoval COURSE',
    'VITAMIN D',
    'liquid predominant diet',
    'formula', 
    'vitamin D supplementation',
    'tyrosine supplementation',
    'meals',
    'water'
]]
protein=[nlp.make_doc(text)for text in ['protein']]  # Lookbehind for "protein"

phrase_matcher.add("DIET",None, *food_list)
#phrase_matcher.add("protein",None, *protein)

text = 'She intake of 3 meals per day of low protein foods.Encouraged intake of water instead of calorie drinks. Aim for <10 gm per day of protein from the diet. Tyrosine supplementation, Vitamin D'
doc1  = nlp(text)
matches = phrase_matcher(doc1)
# Assign labels and update Doc object with entities
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'COLOR'
    span = doc1[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
    print(rule_id, span.text)


# Initialize a list to store entities
# Filter spans to keep only the longest or first matching entity
filtered_entities = []
for match_id, start, end in matches:
  span = Span(doc1, start, end, label="DIET")
  filtered_span = filter_spans([span])[0]
  print(f"Filtered Span: {filtered_span.text}")  # Check filtered span text
  filtered_entities.append(filtered_span)


# Add filtered entities to doc
for ent in filtered_entities:
  if not any(ent.start <= token.idx < ent.end for token in doc1):
    doc1.ents = list(doc1.ents) + [ent]

# Render the entity's
displacy.render(doc1, style="ent")
```

However, the About code snippet is throwing an error.
I have used the suggested `filter_span`

```
  DIET meals
DIET water
DIET vitamin D supplementation
DIET formula
DIET tyrosine supplementation
Filtered Span: meals
Filtered Span: water
Filtered Span: vitamin D supplementation
Filtered Span: formula
Filtered Span: tyrosine supplementation

  ValueError: [E1010] Unable to set entity information for token 30 which is included in more than one span in entities, blocked, missing or outside.
```

Any help or support is appreciated

Comment: I suggest to check again you code, seems that `displacy` hasn't been previously defined: `NameError: name 'displacy' is not defined`